# Kaggle notebook multiple commands in one cell?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, kaggle

I'm trying to get the modes of a couple of columns by giving all the commands in  one cell itself , rather than having to do it for each column in a separate cell , but the output gives only the  result of the first column. How do I do it?

```
 data['director'].mode()
 data['cast'].mode()
 data['country'].mode()
 data['date_added'].mode()
 data['rating'].mode()
```

Output:

```
 0    TV-MA
```

Comment: In general, only the output of the last command is shown in notebooks; you should use `print` statements if you want all of them shown.

Comment: Use print statement